# Why is my c720 Chromebook extremly slow and unresponsive with latest Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, chromebook

My girlfriend bought a C720 Acer Chromebook, but as it's doesn't support java and skype she want's to return it.
I offered alternative a Linux - Kubuntu.
Now I instaled it [following this guide](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.no/2013/05/chrubuntu-one-script-to-rule-them-all_31.html).

Everything went like a charm, but now, after I Login... I can't practically do anything. It's so slow... When I try to open K, or press no Wireless icon, only half of the menu shows up, and none of selections do any further action. For example: on wifi, when it's half opened, I can't click on desired WiFI to join; It does nothing. If I click on K it's in half opened stage and if I try to open FireFox or FileBrowser nothing happens.
I'm totaly new to Linux. Some step by step solution would be appropriate.

And is there a way how to turn of or bypass OS Verification i'm more than 100% sure that one time she will press that Spacebar and Chromebook will return to defaults.

Comment: Thanks Jens Erat for making my issue more understandable. Appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

I have the C720 and have the ubuntu install running perfectly using the following guide

http://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/

The only difference from your guide was that I used the XFCE4 install of Unity environment.  I have Skype, Steam, Dropbox, etc.  No lag, everythign running smoothly

I suggest you just start over and delete the chroot running Kubuntu and run it again.

You can also run throught he steps in this guide to help clean up your current install
http://www.maketecheasier.com/8-ways-to-maintain-a-clean-lean-ubuntu-machine/